# Able to conditional format Outlook 2013 calendar where Required Attendee's email domain is anything other than MYCOMPANY.COM?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, conditional-formatting, calendar

I'd like to create a rule that assigns a color to any calendar invite that has any external participant, such as perhaps looking at the domain and seeing their domain is different from my own?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have done a lot of research and test, but didn't find a way to achieve it. But if you receive the meetings with recipients from **a small number of external domains**, it is recommended that you could try to **create a rule to assign meeting requests sent to specific domains to categories**, as shown in the below figure.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.